# Getting ms graph api access token

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get access token for my web app.

the document is said to do something like this
[MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user)

[image]

So I made my code like this... if its incorrect please tell me where..

```
Dictionary<string, object> param_req_access_token = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        param_req_access_token["url"] = $@"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token";
        string str_basic_key = $"{client_id}:{client_secret}";
        byte[] encData_byte = new byte[str_basic_key.Length];
        encData_byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str_basic_key);
        string encodedData = Convert.ToBase64String(encData_byte);
        param_req_access_token["Headers"] = "Authorization: Bearer " + encodedData;
        param_req_access_token["ContentType"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        StringBuilder postData_req_access_token = new StringBuilder();
        postData_req_access_token.Append($"client_id={client_id}");
        postData_req_access_token.Append($"&scope={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(scrope)}");
        postData_req_access_token.Append($"&code={code}");
        postData_req_access_token.Append($"&redirect_uri={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(redirect_uri)}");
        postData_req_access_token.Append($"&grant_type={grant_type}");
        postData_req_access_token.Append($"&client_secret={client_secret}");
        param_req_access_token["postData"] = postData_req_access_token.ToString();
        string responseData_req_access_token = RequestWebPage(param_req_access_token);
```

ANd of course it doesn't work... Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Hi, please refer to the solution I provided below. If it helps your problem, please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it as answer(click on the check mark beside my answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Thanks in advance~

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you did in `RequestWebPage`, I just write a sample to request the access token for your reference:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "client_id", "09451791-883xxxxx" },
                { "scope", "openidxxxx" },
                { "code", "0.ARoATqvJ5Ce91UCEWSMLoxxxxx" },
                { "redirect_uri", "https://hurytest" },
                { "grant_type", "authorization_code" },
                { "client_secret", "aN9nerF4xxxxx" }
            };

            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

            var response = await client.PostAsync("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token", content);

            Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
        }
    }
}
```